# How to add System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser in a System.Windows.Forms.Form

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

I want to add a `WebBrowser(System.Windows.Controls)` 
in a `Form(System.Windows.Forms)` I try this

```
this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
```

but I have an error

```
cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'
```

How I can do that ? I don't want to use `WebBrowser(System.Windows.Forms)` I don't know what is the difference but I need some method existing in `System.Windows.Controls` and not in `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: System.Windows.Controls is WPF, and as such not compatible with WinForms without wrapping it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739902/How-to-Easily-Host-WPF-Control-inside-Windows-Form

Comment: "I don't want to use WebBrowser(System.Windows.Forms)"  Why not?

Comment: @SteveWellens I want to call `InvokeScript();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `ElementHost` control to wrap the `WebBrowser` control for use in Winforms.

Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You need to do something like:

```
var elementHost = new ElementHost();
elementHost.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser();
this.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```